# React Modal JS file not displaying text or SCSS / SAAS info

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

When running this React app my code below isn't displayed with the basic modal. It seems like something isn't linked? Please, any insight would be a massive help and met with gratitude.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./modal.scss";

const Modal = ({ show }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {show ? (
        <div className="modalContainer">
          <div className="modal">
            <header className="modal_header">
              <h2 className="modal_header-title">Modal Title</h2>
              <button className="close">Close</button>
            </header>
            <main className="modal_content">This is modal content</main>
            <footer className="modal_footer">
              <button className="modal-close">Cancel</button>
              <button className="submit">Submit</button>
            </footer>
          </div>
         </div>
        )  : null}
      </>
      );
    };

    export default Modal;
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you use `Modal` component.

Comment: In order to determine what is the reason, we need more info, but from what I see, I assume either your boolean is showing the opposite, I mean it should be false, or you are not calling the component from app.js/index.js